# Getting NullPointer implementing a LinkedSet

Tags: java, linked-list, set

I am trying to make a LinkedSet object class that implements a modified Set interface. I am getting a NullPointerException when I try and check if the firstNode is pointing to null or not. I'm not really sure how to solve this issue.

Here is relevant code.

Constructor for overall Set object

```
public class LinkedSet<T> implements Set<T> {

    private Node firstNode;

    public LinkedSet() {
        firstNode = null;
    } // end Constructor
```

Method that is holding me up

```
public int getSize() {
    int size = 1;
    Node current = firstNode;

    while ((current.next) != null) {
        size++;
        current = current.next;
    }
    return size;
} // end getSize()
```

isEmpty() method

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    Node next = firstNode.next; //Get error here
    if (next.equals(null)) {
       return true;
    }
    return false;
} // end isEmpty()
```

Here is private inner class for Node objects

```
private class Node {
    private T data;
    private Node next; //Get Error here

    private Node(T data, Node next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    } // end Node constructor

    private Node(T data) {
        this(data, null);
    }// end Node constructor
 } // end Node inner Class
```

And lastly here is the main tester method.

```
public class SetTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedSet<String> set = new LinkedSet<String>();
        System.out.println(set.getSize()); //Get error here
    }
}
```

Comment: firstNode = null; at your constructor is throwing that

Comment: In addition to the other suggestions: in `getSize()` I believe you should initialize `size` to 0 and use `current != null` as your `while` condition.

Answer (score 4):

Your set is empty if it has no nodes. Therefore your `isEmpty()` implementation is your problem, since it assumes you always have a `firstNode` even though you explicitly set it to `null` in the constructor.

Try this:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
   return firstNode == null;
}
```

*Edit after the first problem was edited away:*

You still access null (which causes the `NullPointerException`) since you set `current` to `firstNode` which in turn has never been set to anything but null.

Comment: This actually fixes this method, but I'm still having trouble with others.

Comment: Please don't edit out the code that had the problem - then all the answers will seem nonsensical.

Answer (score 2):

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    Node next = firstNode.next; //Get error here
    if (next.equals(null)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
} // end isEmpty()
```

This line gives you NullPointerException, I hope:

```
Node next = firstNode.next; //Get error here
```

Because `firstNode` is probably `null` and not pointing anywhere so far. It's also best practice to handle `NullPointerException`. So, what you should do is:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    if (firstNode == null) { return true;}
    return false;
} // end isEmpty()
```

Also, do not check null as:

`next.equals(null)`

Always check it as:

`null == next` or `next == null`

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if `firstNode` is `null` before you try to access it in the line with the error, since you initialize it with `null`.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
public class LinkedSet<T> implements Set<T> {

    private Node firstNode;

    public LinkedSet() {
        firstNode = null;
    } // end Constructor
```

`firstNode` is null and you are not initializing the memory to the node and accessing it afterwards.That's the reason you are getting null pointer exception because you are accessing null. Change it to.

```
public class LinkedSet<T> implements Set<T> {
private Node firstNode;

public LinkedSet() {
    firstNode = new Node();
} // end Constructor
```

To check if empty

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
   return firstNode==null;
} // end isEmpty()
```

Node Class

```
private class Node {
    private T data;
    private Node next; //Get Error here
    private Node(T data, Node next) {
        next= new Node();
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    } // end Node constructor

    private Node(T data) {
        this(data, null);
    }// end Node constructor
} // end Node inner Class
```

Main

```
public class SetTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedSet<String> set = new LinkedSet<String>();
        System.out.println(set.isEmpty());
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that make this.isEmpty() always false though?